# Use jsonb structure in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have one table emp3

````
```
   - id int not null
   - lvl varchar
   - includes jsonb
```
````

Table structure :

| id | lvl | inculdes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jj~ii | null |
| 2 | jj~ii~aa | null |
| 3 | ii | null |

I want to update the includes column based on the lvl column by splitting on '~'. I'm able to do it like this :

````
```
       do $$declare 
          i record;
          tbl_var jsonb := null;
          tbl_var1 text[];
          part varchar;
            begin
              for i in select * from emp3 where includes is null
               loop 
                 if array_length(string_to_array(i.lvl, '~'), 1) is not null then 
                 tbl_var1 := null;
                  foreach part in array string_to_array(i.lvl, '~')
                   loop
                    tbl_var1 := concat(tbl_var1, '{"lvls" : "',part,'"}');
                      UPDATE emp3 set includes = tbl_var1 where id = i.id;
                   end loop;
                else
                 tbl_var := i.lvl;
                 UPDATE emp3 set includes = tbl_var where id = i.id;
                end if;
              end loop;
             end $$;
```
````

Output after executing query :

| id | lvl | inculdes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a~b | ["{"lvls" : "a"}", "{"lvls" : "b"}"] |
| 2 | a~b~c | ["{"lvls" : "a"}", "{"lvls" : "b"}","{"lvls" : \c"}"] |
| 3 | a | ["{"lvls" : "a"}"] |

But i want to output to be in this format :

| id | lvl | inculdes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a~b | [{"lvls" : "a"}, {"lvls" : "b"}] |
| 2 | a~b~c | [{"lvls" : "a"}, {"lvls" : "b"},{"lvls" : "c"}] |
| 3 | a | [{"lvls" : "a"}] |

without the escaped character and " not appending in start and end of dict.
How can this be achieved

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to properly format the question, if someone knows please do that so that the question can be in a good structure (table n code)

Comment: I removed the tags for the unsupported Postgres versions (9.1, 9.3) as neither of them supported `jsonb`

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using [jsonb_build_object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html):

array_append(tbl_var1, jsonb_build_object('lvls',part));